# Dropdown with UL in it -> should expand due to amount of list items

Tags: php, html, css

I have a very specific problem with the div in a dropdown.

The `<ul>` within the dropdown is created by a php-foreach function and the amount of `<li>` varies.

The width of the dropdown should expand if there are more than one `<li>`, but not more than four in a row. I have to have margin left/right of 20px, a margin top of 12px and a margin between the `<li>` of 10px.

I already built it with a fixed width for four or more than four `<li>` (with nth-child etc) but now I have the order to make it smaller if there are only one or two items in it.

I tried different things but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: css max-width? You should post your html and css in a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is there a way to set min AND max-width at the same time?